# socket.recv() in python truncating output on newline?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

### Bottom-Line

- The script does not print everything from socket.recv() to the linux terminal.
- If I do the same thing in the interpreter, it prints all the data to the terminal.

(let's say i use local gateway for ip and 23 for port, so telnetting into my router)

```
import socket
q = socket.socket()
q.connect(ip, port)
data = q.recv(1024)
print data
```

### Output in interpreter is four lines:

(some alt-code gibberish or whatever on the first line)
RT v24-sp2 std (c) 2012 NewMedia-NET GmbH
Release: 03/21/12 (SVN revision: 18795)
DD-WRT login:

### Output from script:

(just the alt-code gibberish from the first line)

Any advice regarding why this is happening and how to correct it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: That is not how you use `recv`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14168176/1832154 and many other places that discuss socket recv.

Comment: I'm using it to grab banners from services

Comment: That is irrelevant. The parameter for `recv` is only the maximum amount you might receive, there is no guarantee that you will receive that much.

Comment: As mmgp said in the comments, `socket.recv()` does not guarantee how many bytes you will receive upon calling it. The integer parameter simply sets the maximum limit for what the socket will try to read. You need a `while` loop to keep recv'ing until you get the amount of bytes you desire.

Comment: Thank you for the useful information - this helps clarify my understanding of recv quite a bit =). If this is not how I use recv, what is my best option for receiving an arbitrary amount of information from a socket - like grabbing a banner from a service running on a server?

Comment: the problem is just that the amount of bytes I want is an arbitrary amount that is less than 1024

Answer (score 1):

When running the commands slowly one at a time, your router has time to send everything it's planning to send before you have a chance to invoke `q.recv(1024)`.

When you run it from a script, the commands execute in quick succession. When the script executes `q.recv(1024)`, the router has only managed to send some data, not all of it.

Since you do not use a loop to go back and try reading more data, that's the end, you will not receive (or print) any more data.

(By the way, what in the world is "alt-code gibberish"? What you should be getting here is some binary data that's part of the telnet protocol negotiation.)

Comment: by alt-code gibberish I was looking for a quick way out when I lacked requisite understanding of the phenomenon to phrase it properly

Comment: as a follow-up, is there a way to strip the binary data and print it as hex?..Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure, you could walk through the data you receive and print ASCII characters if it's printable ASCII and hex bytes if it's not, but the real solution here is to use a [telnet client](http://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html) when connecting to a telnet server, not just a raw socket. The telnet client will then interpret the telnet protocol correctly and separate the header and options negotiation exchanges from the payload data.

Comment: I don't want to connect to the telnet server though - it's just an example target - I suppose the intent of this is just a personal exploration into networking in python, but I was writing a banner grabbing script to gather information about services running on a server